# Wordpress - custom taxonomy - no archive

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Essentially I've built my site on a theme that has quite a lot of missing code, for features that should be there. I've managed to sort out everything apart from this.

The site has a portfolio post type. Essentially categories are being created, and posts can be assigned to these categories. A post is created, however an archive page for categories returns 'Page not found'.

My functions.php part for this is as follows:

```
  /**  taxonomy.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function create_portfolio_taxonomy()
{
    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio-category',
        'portfolio',
        array(
            'labels'            => array(
                'name'              => _x('Categories', 'portfolio', 'awe'),
                'singular_name'     => _x('Category', 'portfolio', 'awe'),
                'menu_name'         => __('Categories', 'awe'),
                'all_items'         => __('All Categories', 'awe'),
                'edit_item'         => __('Edit Category', 'awe'),
                'view_item'         => __('View Category', 'awe'),
                'update_item'       => __('Update Category', 'awe'),
                'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Category', 'awe'),
                'new_item_name'     => __('New Category Name', 'awe'),
                'parent_item'       => __('Parent Category', 'awe'),
                'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Category:', 'awe'),
                'search_items'      => __('Search Categories', 'awe'),
            ),
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug' => 'category',
            ),
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomy', 0);

add_action('init', 'custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite');
function custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  custom post type 
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_post_type' );
function create_portfolio_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' )
      ),
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
      'hierarchical' => 'true',
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

As you can see I can sort via category on my portfolio section on my home page - willd.co.uk/#clients

Post page - http://willd.co.uk/portfolio/victoria-front-of-house/
Category page that doesn't work - http://willd.co.uk/category/eggs/

From what I gather Wordpress goes through a hierarchy of potential templates and will then come to archive.php

I'm new to php, so really just using tutorials and logic to get everything working.

I have flushed permalinks.

I'm thinking perhaps I need to make create and edit a portfolio-archive.php or taxonomy.php file rather than letting it fall to archive.php although having looked at tutorials and other stackoverflow answers I haven't been able to work this out.

Many thanks for any help,

W

Comment: WordPress defualt blog category has the slug of "category" so it might be better to name it something else as it may be trying to overwtie it. Also try creating taxonomy-category.php file and populate it with the archive page's content in the root of your theme

Comment: Thank you Richard - I think the slug was overwriting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to arrange it using to arrays and you can notice a lot of things, changed the slug to portfolio-category and I think it will be working now.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );

    function create_portfolio_taxonomies(){
            $labels = array(
                    'name'              => _x('Categories', 'portfolio', 'awe'),
                    'singular_name'     => _x('Category', 'portfolio', 'awe'),
                    'menu_name'         => __('Categories', 'awe'),
                    'all_items'         => __('All Categories', 'awe'),
                    'edit_item'         => __('Edit Category', 'awe'),
                    'view_item'         => __('View Category', 'awe'),
                    'update_item'       => __('Update Category', 'awe'),
                    'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Category', 'awe'),
                    'new_item_name'     => __('New Category Name', 'awe'),
                    'parent_item'       => __('Parent Category', 'awe'),
                    'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Category:', 'awe'),
                    'search_items'      => __('Search Categories', 'awe'),
                );

               $args = array('hierarchical'      => true,
                             'labels'            => $labels,
                             'show_ui'           => true,
                             'show_admin_column' => true,
                             'query_var'         => true,
                             'rewrite'           => array(
                                                       'slug' => 'portfolio-category',
                                                    );
                         );
        register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-category', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );

    }
```

Another resource you can look into is **zilla-portfolio** another is **sequence slider**  these plugin have used it well.

Comment: I think there's a typo here --- the fourth line of code should be completely deleted? the << 'labels'            => array( >>

Comment: @user3445853 You were correct my friend, thank you for pointing out, I have updated the answer now.